# How to mock/patch a function without return value that changes parameter values?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Say that I have a function

```
def change_dict_value(abc):
  # doing a lot of calculations here
  # and finally generate a new dictionary efg
  abc.update(efg)
```

How do I mock/patch the function to set abc's return value after processing by change_dict_value?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?

Comment: @SV-97 No. I mean the function does not have a return value. how do I its effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `side-effect` [parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect).

```
def mock_change_dict_value(abc):
    # Change abc
    abc.update(efg)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
>>> mock = Mock()
>>> mock.side_effect = mock_change_dict_value
>>> mock()
```